# visual studio/ C++ unresolved external symbol: public static class

Tags: visual-c++

I'm a newbee in C++,

I'm trying to make a library for my program, and I've got this problem.

I have a .h file for declaration member functions.

```
class Quaternion
//qua.h
{
private:
public:
inline static Quaternion M2Qua(Matrix&);
}
```

a matrix.h file for declaration matrix class. And an Qua.cpp file for the define function, and I want to link the M2Qua function in the qua.h file.

```
//Qua.cpp
Quaternion Quaternion::M2Qua(Matrix& R)
{
}
```

When I called the function in my main program, the compiler printed an error.

the error is:
LNK 2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class Quaternion _cdecl Quaternion::M2Qua(class Matrix&)

I read some relevant topics but I can't figure out where exactly the problem is. I just suppose it relates to the static member, that I declared in qua.h file. I hope someone helps me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be sure to look at the warnings as well, C4506 "no definition for inline function" tells you what is going to happen.  Delete `inline` from the declaration.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did, and it doesn't work. Even I just test with the class and no called function in the main program. The error still appears.

Comment: It appears you haven't actually added `Qua.cpp` to the project. It's not being linked in.